# Convert fetch to axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, fetch, vuetify.js

I did a 'get' with fetch but I want to do it with axios, could someone help me convert this code to axios?

detail: detail: I made the request to get an image, and I use the blob to be able to show this image to the user, and I would like to do that with axios as well.

Code:

```
 const image = (url) =>
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
          return response.blob();
      })
      .then(
        (blob) =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = reject;
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
          })
      );
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt. Did your read the axios docs? Where are you stuck, what part is so hard to convert?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const image = async (url) =>
    await axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      // can access blog directly from response... 
    }
```

Read more about axios [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro)

Comment: I tried this and it worked, but i need the blob. I request an image from api and this image comes in compressed base64...

Answer (score -2):

Here: I am assuming this is a get request?

```
    const image = async (url) => {
    
   return await axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
          return response.blob();
      })
      .then(
        (blob) =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = reject;
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
          })
      );
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is a get request

Comment: In this code, response.blob() doesn't work, the message does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse', and i need this because i request an image from api, and this api comes in compressed base64